# Interaktive image crop and image grid in julia

Tags: julia

i want to write a little script that dies the following and need some tips on which approach would be the best.

I have a number of groups of raster images, each of which contains 3 images. Each group of images should be consecutively shown to the user, who then selects one of the 3 images. The user then should select an area of the chosen image which the image is cropped to. All the selected and cropped images of all groups should then be annotated and arranged in a grid and saved to a jpeg file.

I have some experience with Julia but no experience at all with images/guis and similar things in Julia.

I think the image grid and the annotations could be done with ImageView.jl but I didn't mange to combine those two and save it to a file. i guess for the first part with the image selection and cropping I need either gtk or Cairo but maybe you have better ideas... 
Can someone help me figuring out a good workflow and some key functions  to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's probably all broken but investigate things like https://github.com/jverzani/GtkInteract.jl and Tim Holy's Immerse.jl (although I think that's Missing in Action). Cairo will export PNGs, but no JPEGs, I think.

Comment: I think FIleIO.jl defines saving rules (by callout to appropriate package) to do the saving/loading of jpeg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ImageView's interactive zoom. Make sure you hold on to the returned output from `view`, and inspect the fields to figure out the current zoom state. Use those bounds to define the crop region for the other images, and then just concatenate the cropped images together.